# Ajax return formatted integers

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a SQL statement to retrieve int values formatted with 2 decimals:

```
SELECT FORMAT(`budget`.`transportation`,2), FORMAT(`budget`.`accomodation`,2) 
FROM `budget`
```

My `json_encode` returns:

```
{
 "FORMAT(`budget`.`transportation`,2)":"343.00",
 "FORMAT(`budget`.`accomodation`,2)":"343.00"
}
```

I want to display it in my form `$("#transportation")` and `$("#accomodation")`

Here is a portion of my Ajax to handle it:

```js
var budget       = $("#modal-budget"), 
    activityName = $("#modal-activityName"); 

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax.php",
        data: {
                // Data to server
              },
        success : function(data) {
            // Parse result as JSON
            var res = JSON.parse(data);
...
```

```js
// Update modal fields
transportation . text(res.transportation);
accomodation . text(res.accomodation);
```

The issue is with the values returned by Ajax:

```js
{
 "FORMAT(`budget`.`transportation`,2)":"343.00"
 ...
}
// Instead of: 
{
 "transportation":"343.00", 
 "accomodation":"343.00"
}
```

Is there a way to solve this or make Ajax return currency format for each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE AS to set alias name

```
SELECT FORMAT(budget.transportation,2) AS transportation, 
       FORMAT(budget.accomodation,2) AS accomodation 
FROM budget
```

Then your returning json data should be like this:

```
{"transportation":"343.00", "accomodation":"343.00"}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It worked as i wanted #jogesh_pi  by using AS as alias